# return undefined instead of the wanted value React-Redux and Redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I created a slice with createSlice using the redux toolkit.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const selectAppColorChange = state => state.lightMode;

const appColorChangeSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'appColorChange',
    initialState: {lightMode: true},
    reducers: {
        changeState: state => {
            state.lightMode = state.lightMode ? false : true;
        }
    }
});

export const { changeState } = appColorChangeSlice.actions;
export default appColorChangeSlice.reducer;
```

Then I created a button with the initial state as the sun image which will change itself to the moon image when clicked and opposite.

```
import Sun from '../../images/icon-sun.svg';
import Moon from '../../images/icon-moon.svg';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { selectAppColorChange, changeState } from '../App/appColorChangeSlice';

export function TodoHeader(){
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const buttonIconBool = useSelector(selectAppColorChange);
    function changeBackground () {
        dispatch(changeState());
        console.log(buttonIconBool);
    }
    return (
        <div className='todoHeader'>
                <h1>TODO</h1>
                <img className='changeColorButton' 
                src={buttonIconBool ? Sun : Moon} 
                onClick={changeBackground}
                alt='change_state_button'/>
            </div>
    )
}
```

But an error occur that the moon always appears and when I clicked on the moon it stays remained, to find out more and fix the problem I console.log(buttonIconBool) to the console. Instead of giving the boolean value that I want it returns undefined.
How can I fix this? Thanks for answering my question!

Comment: Include your `store.js` or the file where `configureStore` is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have the wrong selector.

Assuming your have given `appColorChange` in your `store.js` like this,

```js
import appColorChange from "******/appColorChange**.js";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
       appColorChange: appColorChange
    },
})
```

then the selector should be,

```js
export const selectAppColorChange = state => state.appColorChange.lightMode;
```

or

```js
const buttonIconBool = useSelector(state => state.appColorChange.lightMode);
```

> The selector will be called with the entire Redux store state as its only argument.

Reference: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector